# Need to remove billing and shipping adders in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a problem with my magento store. In my magento store have only the downloadable products.

Our clients & customer asked me to "we buy a downloadable products, then why your site ask me to filling the billing & shipping address". They felt it was a huge process to complete thier checkout.

Note: All the transactions are make by PAY PAL.

Help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento does alot of calculation based upon the shipping address. Maybe change your checkout so they only have to fill in one address that duplicates the address to shipping address.